# Holding job on qsub

Tags: shell, unix, pbs, qsub

I need help on launching a job using qsub which is dependent on multiple previous jobs. Say I have submitted following jobs

```
qsub -N job1 -cwd  job1_script
qsub -N job2 -cwd  job2_script
qsub -N job3 -cwd  job3_script
```

I need to hold a job dependent on all three jobs above.

I know we can do this as :

```
qsub -hold_jid job1,job2,job3 -cwd  job4_script
```

Is there a way where to pass job ids to `-hold_jid` as pattern .Something like this

```
 qsub -hold_jid job* -cwd  job4_script
```

I will be submitting N number of jobs and needs to hold the last one till N jobs are complete, hence I am looking for a way to do it.

Comment: Which `qsub` are you using? PBS? Torque? Grid Engine?

Comment: Hi Keith, PBS it is !!

Comment: Are you sure this is PBS Professional? I am asking again, since `-hold_jid` is an SGE option.